# JavaFX Button does not scale with windows font size settings

Tags: java, fonts, javafx

The buttons in my JavaFX application look very nice on all operating systems with default font settings.
Howerver, if I increase the scale of text in the windows control panel,
the text on the JavaFX buttons increases wheareas the button size stays the same.
Therefore I get a button with 3 letters and an ellipsis (...).

How can I achieve that control elements in javaFX scale according to the system font?

Comment: Perhaps this [related article on DPI font scaling on Windows](http://news.kynosarges.org/2013/08/09/javafx-dpi-scaling/) might give you some insights into solving your issues.  You might want to update your question to note the OS/Java version you are using and include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody could replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of multiple things.
First the layout in wich are your button.
And if you set a hard size to your button.

verify that you don't set a size to your button. And the parent layout size to a size smaller than the button size.

And try to set your button size with `button.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)` if it's still not working your parent layout is probably the cause.

You should try to play a little with [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/) for a better understanding of how layout works